# Is love and marriage all part of Destiny?

Tags: karma, marriage, destiny

If a person has marriage written in his/her destiny, does it make sense for that person to make effort and find the right person to marry?
Or can the person sit back and let destiny play its role to unite the two people when the time is right?

Comment: Yes, everything is a part of one's destiny. Who you marry, whether you get married at all, etc. is all part of your Prarabdha Karma.

Comment: See if you try to find the person for marriage, if someone is in your destiny than you find, Universe will create hindrance for you in finding because that's not written in your destiny. But destiny and fate are entirely different. Destiny can be changed through devotion to Paramatma and engaged in Yoga. Here first step in yoga is to follow Dharma. The more you follow Dharma, Karma's pain and reactions will slowly subside and thereby destiny can be changed!

Answer (score 2):

Gita says:

> 18.61 O Arjuna, the Lord resides in the region of the heart of all creatures, revolving through Maya all the creatures (as though) mounted on a machine!

So whether a person will make effort or sit back is also decided by God, Whom we also name 'destiny'.

According to Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita

> The birth, the death and the **marriage**--all happen by the will of God.